# Set a parameter from path to each URL

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have a Joomla site which shows coming soon template if the user goes to the page https://mysite.com

However, I'd like a way to bypass the coming soon page by adding a parameter to the URL. For example, if the site visitor types https://mysite.com?pass then they'll be able to see the original template and not the coming soon page. In my template php file, I've been able to do that using this code

```
if (isset($_GET['pass'])) {
// show template instead of coming soon page
}
```

This works in showing the home page, but if I navigate to another page, I still see the coming soon page, so I'd like to pass the variable 'pass' to all the other urls. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to drop a variable into the session like this:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$pass = false;
// if the pass query is ever present, then set pass to true and add it to the session as well
if (isset($_GET['pass'])) {
    $pass = true;
    $session->set('pass', $pass);
} else {
    // no pass query, but check the session to see if this person already has a pass from an earlier request. The second param is the default value.
    $pass = $session->get('pass',false);
}
// now just check $pass for truthiness.
```

Note also that the orthodox way of doing this is to customise the site offline page and then allow offline access to some users. But you do you.

Comment: Don't use super globals in Joomla